# Missing FROM-clause in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following query keeps returning a `missing FROM-clause entry for table "tags"` error, but I'm not sure why:

```
SELECT tags.id, tags.user_id, LOWER(tags.tag) AS tag, tags.detail, us.email
FROM user_settings us
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[$1]) AS selected_tags(tag)
  LEFT JOIN admin.tags tags
    ON tags.tag = selected_tags.tag
  WHERE tags.user_id = us.id
    AND selected_tags.tag IS NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the LOWER(tags.tag) and tags.detail in your initial SELECT,  you need to make a change like the following (NOTE: Added another LEFT JOIN right after the first FROM):

```
SELECT tags.id, tags.user_id, LOWER(atags.tag) AS tag, atags.detail, pl.email
FROM user_settings us
  LEFT JOIN admin.tags atags
    ON tags.tag = selected_tags.tag
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[$1]) AS selected_tags(tag)
  LEFT JOIN admin.tags tags
    ON tags.tag = selected_tags.tag
  WHERE tags.user_id = us.id
    AND selected_tags.tag IS NULL
);
```

Comment: I get the same `missing FROM-clause entry for table "tags"` error after making the above changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select from a WHERE NOT EXISTS subquery. Use a JOIN instead.

```
  SELECT tags.id, tags.user_id, LOWER(tags.tag) AS tag, tags.detail, pl.email
  FROM user_settings us
  JOIN (
    SELECT 1
    FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[$1]) AS selected_tags(tag)
    LEFT JOIN admin.tags tags
      ON tags.tag = selected_tags.tag
    WHERE selected_tags.tag IS NOT NULL
  ) t on t.user_id = us.id ;
```

Comment: I get a `column t.user_id does not exist` error after changing to this structure.